# How can I perform integral on a select area from ''active'' line plot - python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am looking for help in python for:
When I create a plot (x,y) in Python, for example, I have a potential vs. time plot. Is there a way to select a specific area from an "interactive" plot, and then a way to see the integral value result from the selected area, for example, a ''an updated textbox of the value"?

1. When I have an active plot (x,y) (line)
2. I can choose an area from the plot
3. and see the integral value automatically or by pressing a button.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: These kind of questions need a little code example by yourself to show what you've done thus far because it makes us think its homework. Posting this question as new instead of updating from your previous similar question is not the way to go. So, regardless of answer by user Ianhi show what you tried before reading it. EoR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the correct tool to accomplish this is the [SpanSelector](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/gallery/widgets/span_selector.html). Below is some code that adjusts the matplotlib example to do what you want. It will put the value of the integral into the plot title, but you could also print it out or save it to a variable if you wanted. Finally I also added a gray region to show what the selected region is.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import SpanSelector

# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, 0.01)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x) + x

ax.plot(x, y, '-')

# create the gray span to show what we've selected
selected = ax.axvspan(0, 0, color='black', alpha=.25)
selected.set_visible(False)

def onselect(xmin, xmax):
    # calculate the integral
    indmin, indmax = np.searchsorted(x, (xmin, xmax))
    indmax = min(len(x) - 1, indmax)
    integral = np.trapz(y[indmin:indmax], x[indmin:indmax])
    ax.set_title(f"The integral of the selected area is {integral}")
    
    # update the visualization of the selected area
    selected.set_visible(True)
    xy = selected.get_xy()
    xy[[0,1],0] = xmin
    xy[[2,3],0] = xmax
    selected.set_xy(xy)

    fig.canvas.draw()

span = SpanSelector(ax, onselect, 'horizontal', useblit=True,
                rectprops=dict(alpha=0.5, facecolor='red'))
# Set useblit=True on most backends for enhanced performance.


plt.show()
```

[image]